# In Laravel, is it possible to dynamically extend session time based on which routes are accessed?

Tags: php, laravel, session

The title pretty much sums it up my problem.

The company I work at has a Laravel application where session time is set to expire on the `config/session.php` in **120 minutes**, and that is the default behavior and we don't want to change this value.

But there is a certain feature of the system where the user has to answer an extensive form/questionnaire, **that can take more than 3 or 4 hours to finish** if the user is slow to type or goes back to reconsider some answers before submitting.

The thing is some users are still not finished with all questions and session expires making them lose progress, sometimes they only find out about the session being expired minutes later when they change to the "next page" of questions. We thought about saving the already filled data, but also even if we persist the content with AJAX calls, saving to DB the already filled parts, it is still a bad UX to need to login again while answering the form because they need to follow the links again to go into the form page anyway. We are having a lot of complaints from clients because of that session expiration.

The best scenario would be to create some kind of function on the `FormController.php` that when the user enters the forms page or some others specific routes, we do something like `session()->extendSessionInMinutes(360)`. I did some research but coulnd't find anything like that on Laravel docs (please mind we are using `Laravel 8.1`) or on Stackoverflow. Read a lot of things on this topic this week, like solutions about creating a new middleware that gives different session lifetime depending on user roles or something like that, but this option is not useful for us.

I'm working on a solution that will add a **new variable on session using a solution like** `session()->put('time_to_logout', now()->addHours(2))` to know the exact time the session reaches 2 hours, so I can **increase the lifetime to 5 hours for the default value on `SESSION_LIFETIME`** and add a JS function to check every 30 min if we need to logout and redirect user to a logout page, and if he is on the forms page we stop checking.

But I don't think that's actually a good solution but I can't seem to think on another one. Is there a way to do what I want by just extending the session time in some way? Or recreating the session without impact to the users (*my bet is that would mess with the CSRF token on the form*), and in a way seamlessly recreating the session with more 2 hours while he keeps filling the form, without noticing any changes?

When session is created there is no way to change it's expiration? Is there some kind of PHP library that could help me here without having to change too much of the Laravel default session related functions?

*Thanks in advance for any input.*

Comment: The session should expire when it's idle, meaning no traffic is being passed. If a single page takes 4-5 hours, then you can add an ajax call every X minutes that would interact with the server and thus extend the session.

Comment: Did you consider using cookies to store progress henceits not affected by session expiration ? As your thought process, extending the session time is doable with a middleware using config::set();. So you can add this to preferred routes. But it might affect the CSRF token anf leads to issues. Theres a wayaround to mitigate that as well but i would highly recommend not to do that hence its going to fail the qhole purpose of having CSRF protection. If the saving into db is a greater work just give it a thought on going with cookies.

Comment: +1 to anyber's suggestion, and there are packages like [Laravel Caffeine](https://github.com/GeneaLabs/laravel-caffeine) that do that automatically (although last time I used that one, I had to extend it to work with my needs, but it's a pretty simple package)

Comment: Session expiration doesn't exactly depends on the user inactivity. If the application uses absolute expiration , then the session will be expired regardless of user activity.  Also what about using indexedDB ?it can hold pretty much everything within a single origin.

Comment: Isn't it the csrf expiration you may have to handle ? You can regenerate it during submit

Answer (score 0):

**Yes you can**. And you need to do following-

1. **Only a way through middleware you can change the session lifetime dynamically**. Because changing it through any controller  **(without middleware) will not change the session value** as the session will already gets started. So you need a middleware. Like Below-

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

class ChangeSessionValueDynamically
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, $next)
    {
        $lifetime = 1440; /* Minutes*/
        config(['session.lifetime' => $lifetime]); /* Helper function */
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

2. After that you need to add that middleware in $middlewarePriority array in  app/Http/Kernel.php file that must executes before Laravel runs its own "StartSession" middleware. Like below-

Add `\App\Http\Middleware\ChangeSessionValueDynamically::class,` just before to `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,`.

```
/**
     * The priority-sorted list of middleware.
     *
     * This forces non-global middleware to always be in the given order.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewarePriority = [
     ....
     ....
        \App\Http\Middleware\ChangeSessionValueDynamically::class
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
     ....
     ....   
    ];
```

3. Give Alias name of `\App\Http\Middleware\ChangeSessionValueDynamically::class` like below -

```
/**
    * The application's route middleware.
    *
    * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
    *
    * @var array
    */
   protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ....
    ....
       'dynamic_session' => \App\Http\Middleware\ChangeSessionValueDynamically::class,
    ....   
    ....
   ];
```

4. Include that middleware in Routes as -

```
A) For Group Routes- 
Route::group([.., 'middleware' => ['dynamic_session', ..]], function () {
    ..
    Route::get('route_1', ['uses' => 'AbcController@index', 'as' => 'abc.index']);
    ..
}

B) OR For single Route-
Route::get('route_1', ['uses' => 'AbcController@index', 'as' => 'abc.index'])->middleware('dynamic_session');
```